# Finding linux version inside a device driver

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver

I am new to linux device driver development. I am trying to write a `simple hello world module` that would display the version of kernel running on the system where I try to insert `hello_world` module into kernel.

I used `LINUX_VERSION_CODE` in version.h to get linux version and built the module. 
When I try to insert the ko file on a different system other than where it was built, it still shows the version of kernel where it was built

I believe issue lies with using `C macro`.
Can someone help me how to find linux version of local machine where the ko is to be inserted instead of finding version of kernel where my module gets built

Answer (score 1):

You're right - `LINUX_VERSION_CODE` is a macro that provides compile-time info about the version of the Linux headers that you're using to compile the module. The macro cannot have any knowledge about the version of the kernel that the module will actually be loaded into.

The `utsname()` function in `<linux/utsname.h>` provides a pointer to a `new_utsname` struct, which has `sysname`, `release` and `version` members that contain what you're looking for.

The information from these members is used in `/proc/version`, as shown in `fs/proc/version.c` :

```
static int version_proc_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v)
{
    seq_printf(m, linux_proc_banner,
        utsname()->sysname,
        utsname()->release,
        utsname()->version);
    return 0;
}
```

`linux_proc_banner` is a string that is currently defined as follows :

```
const char linux_proc_banner[] =
    "%s version %s"
    " (" LINUX_COMPILE_BY "@" LINUX_COMPILE_HOST ")"
    " (" LINUX_COMPILER ") %s\n";
```

On my system, reading `/proc/version` - and thus reading these members - results in obtaining the following string :

```
Linux version 4.1.6-1-ARCH (builduser@tobias) (gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Aug 17 08:52:28 CEST 2015
```

Thus, `sysname` is `Linux`, `release` is `4.1.6-1-ARCH`, and `version` is `#1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Aug 17 08:52:28 CEST 2015`.